# Best way to pass process.env.ENV to my react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

My react app needs to know if the ENV is production or development, and I set it in my .env file on my express server perfectly, but I don't know how to inject that successfully into the client code which needs to know the ENV to determine if the link is localhost or mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do this in your webpack routine. It can be achieved with the DefinePlugin method: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Webpack or any other module bundler? You can configure Webpack to use a different config dependent on your environment.